# Bootstrap Modal not working after validaion, but alert works

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, forms, validation

I have a preview button in bootstrap 4. I want to show validation error if the form is not valid and show a modal window if the form is valid.

I have this code.

```
    $("#previewBtn").click(function(event) {
    //$("#exampleModal").modal("show");  //Works fine if I uncomment

    //Fetch form to apply custom Bootstrap validation
    var form = $("#order-form")
    //alert(form.prop('id')) //test to ensure calling form correctly

    if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        //alert("Validated!");
        $("#exampleModal").modal("show");   
    }
    form.addClass('was-validated'); 
  }) //validation end
```

I get validation error if the form is not valid.

I get the modal window if I uncomment the second line to show the modal.

But the modal window is not working in the `else` if there is no errors in the validation.

The `alert` (above show modal) is working in the `else` if there is no errors in the validation.

How can I show the modal window if there is no validation errors?

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery a simple way to show an element is to use .show() method

ex:

```
$("#exampleModal").show();
```

here you can find documentation about .show() http://api.jquery.com/show/

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the value of your form variable.  if it works in position 1 and not in the else then it leads me to think `checkValidity()` is either returning true or the if statement is throwing an exception.

And maybe add a `;` to your `var form` line